# How do I open a script file in RStudio using an R command?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a simple script file called `test.R`. It's saved in the working directory. When I go to `File > Open > test.R`, it opens the file in the editor (without executing the code, which is what I want).

How do I do this by typing a command in the console window? To be clear, I just want to open (**not** execute) the file.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You are looking for [`file.edit`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/file.edit.html)

```
file.edit('test.R')
```

should open the file in an editor (if you are in `RStudio`, this should default to `RStudio`)

Comment: This code works very nicely. Except when I use it in a function *inside a package*, then the file opens outside of RStudio (rather than as another script within RStudio). Any idea why?

Comment: I'd love to know the answer to that to: how can you call the Rstudio editor from within a package function?

Comment: For this problem, try > rstudioapi::navigateToFile("test.R")

Comment: It does not work from the chank inside of *.rmd.

Answer (score 14):

It appears that if you are using RStudio then another option is to use `rstudioapi::navigateToFile("test.R")`

Comment: Thanks. It works from the chank inside of *.rmd.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is the [shell.exec](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/shell.exec) function.

`shell.exec("text.R")` # This will open the file or URL using the path associated with it

Also, I think for your use case. This code snippet might be a little bit useful.

```
file <- "example.csv"
sub_dir <- "subdirectory"
dir.create(sub_dir)
writeLines("myfile",file.path(sub_dir, file))
# Works
shell.exec(file.path(sub_dir, file, fsep = "\\"))
shell.exec(file.path(sub_dir, file))
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue that `utils::file.edit()` within my package opens outside R-studio. I changed it to `usethis::edit_file()`. With this function the file opens inside R-studio.