# Close a script file in Rstudio using code instead of point clicking

Tags: r, rstudio

### How can force close an open script file - or in general an open tab - in RStudio using code?

As pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23750709/6925293) I already know that `file.edit('test.R')` can open a given file.

This is how I usually end a given script file before moving to an other section.

**What I'd like to do, is to start the new section (script file) from closing what was used before.**

For example:
`import_data.R` has code that does all file reading / importing and when that's done, it opens `data_wrangle.R` by calling `file.edit("data_wrangle.R")` where all the transforming, mutating etc is done.
Since I don't need the import code any more, I'd like to close previous script (`import_data.R` in this case) with a line of code.

I did some guesswork calling
`close("./script/test.R")`
or
`rm("./script/test.R")` but they clearly don't serve this purpose.

Comment: Are you just opening the file in order to execute the contents of the file? Then maybe you should just be using `source()` rather than `file.edit()`.

Comment: If it would be available from anywhere I'd think it would have to come from the [rstudioapi](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudioapi) but there doesn't appear to be functions for closing windows.

Comment: I know of `source()` but here i'm thinking of a interactive scenario where script files are not 100% ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rstudioapi` package doesn't have a function to close a file, but it does have one to navigate to it.  So your script could end something like

```
rstudioapi::navigateTo("data_wrangle.R")
rstudioapi::navigateTo("import_data.R")
```

and then I think a Ctrl-W as suggested by @Joyvalley would do what you want.

Comment: I do not know if the times they are a changing but in 2022 there is a function: `documentClose()`

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look to the `.rs.api.documentClose()` function.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Here in 2023, 'executeCommand' is your friend:

`rstudioapi::executeCommand('closeAllSourceDocs')`

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl - w` does the job

Its not exactly what you ask for, but does what you want.

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711853-Keyboard-Shortcuts

Comment: Problem with `Ctrl+w` is, that `file.edit("...")` automatically moves me to the new file. To use `Ctrl+w` i'd have to point-click on the old window and then close it. Not really a shortcut :)

Comment: True, i guess i wouldnt use Rstudio at all to avoid the clicky-pointy thing :-)